# Hot reloading is not working when I use docker compose and webpack-dev-server

Tags: docker, webpack, docker-compose, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

there.
I've been struggling with building Docker（Docker Compose） and Webpack environment for months.

What I want to achieve is hot reloading for a webpack-dev-server running inside a docker container with code changes from outside the container.

Here is what I've been able to do so far...

- If you run webpack-dev-server in the container and make changes to the code in the container by the vim editor, the changes will take effect and hot reloading will work.
- If you start webpack-dev-server locally while the container is running and make code changes locally too, hot reloading will be performed here as well.

Is anyone familiar with Docker and Webpack? If so, I'd like some advice on how to solve this problem.

Here is my `Dockerfile`.

```
# Base image
FROM node:lts-buster-slim

# Create working directory
RUN mkdir -p /app/framer

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app/framer

# Add $PATH
ENV PATH /app/framer/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./framer:/app/framer
      - /framer/node_modules
    expose:
      - 3002
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    environment:
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
      - WDS_SOCKET_HOST=127.0.0.1
      - WDS_SOCKET_PORT=3002
    stdin_open: true
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Here is my webpack-dev-server settings.

```
devServer: {
  open: true,
  static: {
    directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  allowedHosts: 'all',
  hot: true,
  port: 3002,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  client: {
    webSocketURL: 'ws://0.0.0.0:3002/ws',
    reconnect: true,
    overlay: {
      errors: true,
      warnings: false,
    },
  },
},
watchOptions: {
  poll: true,
},
```

In addition, I will put a link to the GitHub repository that I'm working on for your reference.

https://github.com/Bear29ers/framer-motion

What I want to achieve is hot reloading for a webpack-dev-server running inside a docker container with code changes from outside the container.

First, enter the container like this.

```
docker compose exec app bash
```

Then, run webpack-dev-server.

```
npm run dev
```

While running webpack-dev-server inside the container, you change some code in `src/` directory from outside the container.

I want the browser that accesses localhost:3002 to detect the change and reload automatically.

Best regards.

Comment: How is the `dev` script defined in your `package.json` file?

Comment: @HansKilian I forgot to post the link to my GitHub repository. This is the contents of `package.json`. https://github.com/Bear29ers/framer-motion/blob/develop/framer/package.json

Comment: Do you actually need Docker for this use case?  Can you use plain Node without Docker, and without its filesystem isolation features?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for your comment. I know I don't need Docker in this case, and I was told as much when I discussed it with my colleagues.
However, I thought it was not good to just leave what could not be done as it was, so I asked the question because I would really like to know the cause of the problem.